# Is there any way to keep the return type of a function variable?

Tags: c, function, struct, return-type

I want to define a function, that returns either a `struct` with multiple values of variant type or a single `int *` depending on arguments, a user passes over the command line.
I know, that I could just simply always return a `struct` and retrieve the specific values from the `struct` related to users input data, but I was wondering if there is any possibility to state that a function will return either A or B.

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: you can return a "void *" that you can cast in whatever you want. But It would be a very bad practice.

Comment: It would have to be really clear in the documentation of the function, and you loose the interest of type checking. There is no interrest in doing this, it only adds complexity, this is just to say that it is technically possible but it is not a good thing.

Comment: Just do what you suggest in the second sentence of the question, that's exactly the way to go. Return a struct and retrieve the specific values depending on some  "type" field in the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the closest approach would be to return a `union` of structs with additional type info.

```c
typedef struct {
   MyType type;
   int    alpha;
   float  beta;
   char * gamma;
} A;

typedef struct {
   MyType type;
   int *  data;
} B;

typedef union {
  MyType type;
  A a;
  B b;
} Returnable;

// Returnable func (void);
```

However, you need to either check args before function call or `type` field after. In the latter case you lose compiletime type checking and invent runtime type checking, which can be error-prone.

---

As @EricPostpischil suggested in comments, one more approach:

```c
typedef struct {
  int foo;
} A;

typedef struct {
  char bar;
} B;

typedef struct {
  MyType data_type;

  union {
    A a;
    B b;
  } data;
} Returnable2;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the bare `MyType` in the union may need to be in a `struct` of its own, but I'm not digging through the C standard to figure that out, and **IF** the bare `MyType` does need to be in a `struct` to take advantage of the "common sequence of initial members" to allow access to any of the types in a `union`, that's a subtle enough point that a commentless downvote is wasted.

Comment: There is no reason to put `MyType` in the other structures. A better design is to return a structure in which one element indicates a type (via an enumeration, possibly called `MyType`, or similar method) and the other is a union of all possible types to be returned.

Answer (score 4):

No, a function return type has to be determined and fixed during compile time, it cannot be changed during run-time (i.e., based on a user input).

You can however, make use of an array of function pointers to call different functions based on the user input.

Comment: No need for function pointers, just do if-else or switch case and call functions directly.

Comment: @Fredrik Very possible, but that approach will not scale, if the requirement diversifies.

Comment: depends, if switch case is possible it will scale fine as switch case will most likely compile to a jump table.

Comment: How do function pointers help in this situation? At the site where you call a function by pointer, it has to have a single return type. This does not do anything to handle varying return types.

Answer (score 0):

It is IMO better to implement some kind of polimorphism in C

```
#define mul3(x) _Generic((x), \
    double: mul3d, \
    int: mul3i)(x)

int mul3i(const int x)
{
    printf("Mul3 int %d * 3 = %d\n", x, x*2);
    return x * 3;
}

double mul3d(const double x)
{
    printf("Mul3 double %f * 3 = %f\n", x, x*2);
    return x * 3;
}

int main()
{
    mul3(5.0);
    mul3(4);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Ww3Qm5

Comment: Another silent DV-ter

Comment: Since what C standard is that valid?

Comment: c11 - almost 10 y ago.

Comment: Wow, _Generic must have slipped by me so far. Have to try that some time.